# Crawl images from google search with python

Tags: python, image, web-crawler

I am trying to write a script in python in order to crawl images from google search. I want to track the urls of images and after that store those images to my computer.  I found a code to do so. However it only track 60 urls. Afterthat a timeout message appears. Is it possible to track more than 60 images? 
My code:

```
def crawl_images(query, path):

    BASE_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?'\
         'v=1.0&q=' + query + '&start=%d'

    BASE_PATH = os.path.join(path, query)

    if not os.path.exists(BASE_PATH):
        os.makedirs(BASE_PATH)

    counter = 1
    urls = []
    start = 0 # Google's start query string parameter for pagination.
    while start < 60: # Google will only return a max of 56 results.
        r = requests.get(BASE_URL % start)
        for image_info in json.loads(r.text)['responseData']['results']:
            url = image_info['unescapedUrl']
            print url
            urls.append(url)
            image = urllib.URLopener()

            try:
                image.retrieve(url,"model runway/image_"+str(counter)+".jpg")   
                counter +=1
            except IOError, e:
                # Throw away some gifs...blegh.
                print 'could not save %s' % url
                continue

        print start
        start += 4 # 4 images per page.
        time.sleep(1.5)

crawl_images('model runway', '')
```

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Documentation: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

You should get up to 64 results:

> Note: The Image Searcher supports a maximum of 8 result pages. When
>   combined with subsequent requests, a maximum total of 64 results are
>   available. It is not possible to request more than 64 results.

Another note: You can restrict the file type, this way you dont need to ignore gifs etc.

---

And as an additional Note, please keep in mind that this API should only be used for user operations and not for automated searches!

> Note: The Google Image Search API must be used for user-generated
>   searches. Automated or batched queries of any kind are strictly
>   prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [icrawler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/icrawler/0.2.2) package. Extremely easy to use. I've never had problems with the number of images to be downloaded.